# Relative path in server.mappath

Tags: path, itext, relative-path, filepath

I am using iTextSharp to reada pdf file from  file path , edit and open the file in the browser.

The below code works fine when I run it locally. After I publish and host it, I am not able to read the file from the file path. I think I am making some mistake in relative path.

```
 string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Doc/template.pdf");
```

Please help me.

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;


     private void GeneratePDF()
     {

         byte[] bytes = null;



         using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
         {

            string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Doc/template.pdf");
             // Create the form filler
             using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(path))
             {
                 using ( PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms))
                 {
                     StringBuilder sbstring = null;
                     // Get the form fields
                     AcroFields testForm = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
                    ....
                    ....

                     PdfContentByte overContent = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);
                     pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                 }
             }
             bytes = ms.ToArray(); 
         }

         //Writes it back to the client
         Response.Clear();
         Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + 
         sbFileName.ToString() + "");
         Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Relative path is correct. I checked the log and the deployed folder. The pdf file was not included in the package. When it was done, It worked fine.